# VSCode remote Jupyter Notebook - Access the remote jupyter shell in VSCode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I can connect to a remote Jupyter Notebook server with a token from VSCode through the "Python: Specify Jupyter server URI" command from the Command Palette.

However, I couldn't find a way to do this:
Access the remote server's terminal to run command-line Python code. Using the `!` magic in cells itself is not useful as the command line code is interactive.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? gotten into same issue:(

Answer (score 0):

A little late and not sure if it's the answer you were looking for, but I personally prefer to access remote server's terminal from Windows Terminal, you can set a profile for your server as shown here [SSH in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/ssh)

You can mix this with the extension [Windows Terminal Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.windows-terminal) for vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).